# Overwriting Yocto Classes through meta-layer

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bsp

Thanks for your time and support

I am planning to use swupdate for updates. So, I need to create an additional partition in which I need to store the recovery partition.

```
poky/meta/classes/image-live.bbclass
```

is the class which creates partitions and flashes the root file system. I have updated the above file to create one more partition and store the swupdate root filesystem.

How can I override this class in my own BSP layer, I don't want to touch poky source code..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally in *Yocto* there is no way to override *.bbclass* files like with *.bb* files (using *.bbappend*), to archive that it is needed to copy whole class file and move to another layer, I was able to manage that with this configuration:

layer structure:

```
$ tree ../meta-test/
../meta-test/
├── classes
│   └── image-live.bbclass
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
└── recipes-example
    └── example.bb

3 directories, 5 files
```

content of *example.bb* recipe:

```
$ cat ../meta-test/recipes-example/example/example.bb 
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
inherit image-live
```

and finally **really important thing***, the configuration file *conf/bblayers.conf* needs to be configured with this order **meta-test/** above **meta/** layer:

```
$ tail -n6 conf/bblayers.conf 
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/user/poky/meta-test \
  /home/user/poky/meta \
  /home/user/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/user/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  "

$ bitbake -e example -D | grep ^DEBUG:\\sInheriting\\s.*image-live.bbclass\\s\(from
DEBUG: Inheriting /home/user/poky/meta-test/classes/image-live.bbclass (from /home/user/poky/meta-test/recipes-example/example/example.bb:3)
```

*I don't know why bitbake [layer priority](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-BBFILE_PRIORITY) doesn't work here, only  modifying layers order in *conf/bblayers.conf* allows me to achieve the main goal:

```
$ bitbake-layers show-layers
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
layer                 path                                      priority
==========================================================================
meta                  /home/user/poky/meta        5
meta-test             /home/user/poky/meta-test   10
meta-poky             /home/user/poky/meta-poky   5
meta-yocto-bsp        /home/user/poky/meta-yocto-bsp  5
```

layer **meta-test/** below **meta/** in *conf/bblayers.conf*:

```
$ tail -n6 conf/bblayers.conf 
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/user/poky/meta \
  /home/user/poky/meta-test \
  /home/user/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/user/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  "    

$ bitbake -e example -D | grep ^DEBUG:\\sInheriting\\s.*image-live.bbclass\\s\(from
DEBUG: Inheriting /home/user/poky/meta/classes/image-live.bbclass (from /home/user/poky/meta-test/recipes-example/example/example.bb:3)
```

Comment: In Kirkstone yocto in 2023 this solution does not work. When I put custom layer before meta, I get bunch of parsing errors like missing lsb_distro_identifier etc. Does anybody know how to resolve this problem now?

Comment: I have the exact same case in Kirkstone- is there an existing solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

It was dicussed in 2012 on yocto mailing group:
https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2012-January/004379.html

Only creating the same class and reordering layers as astor555 wrote. That your BSP layer will be parsed/used first.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to copy the original `image-live.bbclass` into your own existing layer and rename it to something meaningful (`my-image-live.bbclass`) and then simply inherit it where you need as `inherit my-image-live`

Comment: Tried this but it's not working. It takes the function from the original .bbclass.