# How can I use bitbake to set /etc/timestamp?

Tags: timestamp, yocto, bitbake

I want to create an image that boots up believing that it's in the year 2038 so I can test some epoch stuff on my company's product.

I'm going about this by trying to force a value on the `/etc/timestamp` file. I'm not sure that's a great strategy for this goal; so if it isn't then I'll ask a separate question about what approach I should take.

I found that `image.bbclass` has a function called `rootfs_upate_timestamp`, so I thought to inherit that class and overwrite the function.

Here's the recipe I created. It's located in `./meta-custom-base/recipes-stuff/custom-timestamp/` .

```
# custom-timestamp.bb

inherit image

rootfs_update_timestamp() {
    echo "20380119000000" > ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/timestamp
}
```

The error is a massive wall of red-colored package names, and at the top it reads `custom-timestamp is not a part of the base feeds`

This layer has other recipes that are getting installed, and I've also added a line to the `*image.bbappend` like

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " other-package-that-installs-fine"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " custom-timestamp"
```

So why am I getting this error, and how can I ensure my custom `/etc/timestamp` gets installed?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a packaging problem, see Martin Jansa's answer in 
https://yocto.yoctoproject.narkive.com/9Ceqiqs9/error-gtest-not-found-in-the-base-feed for solution (add `RDEPENDS_$custom-timestamp=""` ) :

That's correct, all files are installed in gtest-dev package.

The problem is the default RDEPENDS from ${PN}-dev to ${PN}

meta/conf/bitbake.conf:RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev = "${PN} (= ${EXTENDPKGV})"

You can either set
ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"
or
RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev = ""

Also see [bitbake error package not found in base feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751444/bitbake-error-package-not-found-in-base-feeds)

i am not sure if you can override timestamp with this ...

Comment: You're right in that ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1" fixes the error, but then I don't think the function ever gets called; none of my debugging file-ops ever seem to occur. I'll try the RDEPENDS

Comment: i think you can not change the timestamp like this at all, this is not a bitbake problem, for this you have to at least patch the kernel / write custom kernel module and replace the default. Whenever Linux has network connectivity it gets the system time from an NTP server and so on...

Answer (score 0):

My situation is only superficially different from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002891/overwriting-yocto-classes-through-meta-layer).

The difference is that I will be targeting the `rootfs-postcommands.bbclass` for its `rootfs_update_timestamp` method.